# Uploading objects to AWS S3 using presigned URLs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I'm looking to use the presigned URL feature to allow users of my serverless application to upload images. After reading it sounds like the perfect solution but I have a question around security.

By using the presigned URL method, the upload happens client side rather than server side and my only concern with this is despite my app requiring authentication before an upload happens it doesn't prevent a user uploading a malicious file as they could bypass by client side checks to determine whether the file is an image or not.

Does anyone have any clarification on this matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. If they can retrieve the pre-signed URL and bypass your client-side logic then they can upload whatever they like using that URL. If you can't completely control the client-side exposure then you can't trust client-side validation and you should implement rules server-side as well. You could use Lambda here, potentially.